# Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies

Tags: android, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, windows-phone

I'm using Xamarin.Forms in Visual Studio 2015 to develop a cross-platform app for mobile. When adding references .dll files, android app is running ok, but app for windows phone 8.1 it has an error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in MyApp.ni.DLL
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Specifications:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Xamarin 4.1.2.18
Xamarin.Forms 2.3.0.107
Targets:
.NET Framework 4.5
ASP.NET Core 1.0
Windows 8
Windows Phone 8.1
XamarinAndroid
Xamarin.iOS
Xamarin.iOS (Classic)

Tested apps on Samsung Note 4 (Marshmallow API-23) and Microsoft Lumia 640 XL (Windows 10 Mobile 10.0.10586.494).